# How to vertically align a POPUP div with DYNAMIC height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Wow I did not expect this to be such a whirlwind. [My page](http://roseannebarr.tumblr.com) has multiple div popups filled with database generated content so each div has a dynamic height. In easier terms it needs to be in the middle of the page and content needs to ALWAYS be in the middle so expand up and down from the center.

Why is this so difficult :( ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think setting the top and bottom margins of each div to 'auto' might center them. I don't know about the smooth effect you have, though.

Comment: I'm gonna edit the effect. Regardless, yes that would center it but it wouldn't vertically align it. The center of the div always needs to be at the center of the page so depending on what content is generated the height needs to expand downward and upward.

Answer (score 0):

Margin : auto, do mention height of container div

Comment: Margin:auto only works for centering statically sized elements.

Comment: Margin:auto centers horizontally, and dynamic means the div doesn't have a set height.

Comment: Oh, I mis understood you. There is no container div because it needs to be centered on the entire page/screen.

Comment: Have a div as container with position: absolute, height : 100%, put you div inside this div with margin:auto

Answer (score 0):

Particularly If you demand browser compatibility, this is more or less impossible in plain HTML/CSS.  I've had luck across browsers when using extraneous `table` elements to contain my content, since tables technically qualify for the `vertical-align` CSS property.  This requires taking stuff that isn't actually tabular (like `div`s) and placing it in little 1x1 `table` + `td` combos, which behave basically like `div`s except they align properly.  For good browser, you could avoid this by giving a div `display:table-cell`, but for crappy browsers it won't work.

You could definitely accomplish this in Javascript, which is heavy-handed, but at least it's effective.  Something like this (Mootools code provided):

```
window.addEvent('load', function() {
    var parentElement = $('parent_element_id');
    var childElement = $('child_element_id');

    var parentHeight = parentElement.getStyle('height');
    var childHeight = childElement.getStyle('height');

    parentElement.setStyles({
        'position' : 'relative'
    });

    childElement.setStyles({
        'position' : 'absolute',
        'top' : (parentHeight - childHeight) / 2
    });

});
```

(The JS code's untested, but you get the picture)